# Difference between Dynamic, Var and Object

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with an exact difference between Dynamic, Var and Object in C# with some programmatic example. I searched online but I am not getting exact difference.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: All types essentially inherit from `object`. `var` is syntactic sugar to save you typing the full type name. In the example `var test = "hello"`, you should understand `var` to be converted to `string` at compile time. `dynamic` doesn't change the type of the object it references, but no checks are performed on calls to `dynamic` at compile type.

Comment: Please note that the best answer in that post is not the accepted one nor the highest score, but Selman Genç's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some differences. Hope this will help to you.

[image: For better understand please refer this]

Comment: In the last cell for Dynamic, it seems there's a typo. It should be 'dynamic' instead of 'var'

Answer (score 1):

I'm C# compiler

- when I see the **object** and **dynamic**, I usually say to myself, these guys can be anything, better ignore all the sweet compiler issues and let the developers take care all by themselves, and let my friend, the C# runtime to work on the issues much later on
- when I see **var**, I know the developer is relying on my to determine the type, so I should do my work :).

---

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic person = new { name = "name" };
    var age = person.age; // throw when you run the code
    var name = person.name; // I'm cool with it

    object isThisLove;
    isThisLove.IsReal(); //compiler will throw
    var isLoveReal = (((Love)isThisLove).IsReal()); // sweet, compiler will ignore, but runtime will throw if love is not Love
}   

public class Love
{
    public bool IsReal() { return false; }
}
```

Comment: @John typo my friend, thanks.